# Find English words with Sound of V or W?

Tags: english, open-ended

Search and find some English words which when written starts with **o** and when speaking they pronounce with sound of **v** or **w**
lets see who ll find maximum words?

Comment: So the first is "o", and it sounds like "v" or "w"?

Comment: Do you mean like 'of"?

Comment: of and o does not gives sound of v or w

Comment: The 'f' is pronounced as 'v'. Your question was not very clear.

Comment: I don't think there is any English word that starts with O yet sounds like V.  At least not in the pronunciation of any majority English speaking country.

Comment: To make this truly a puzzle, you should have a story involving two characters, one with an accent, overhearing some vital clue and reporting that it "started with a w sound" and another "started with a v sound" and the key to the puzzle is that it actually starts with the letter o. Phrased like this, it's not a puzzle at all.

Comment: Why the -8 downvotes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. One  (In english accent = 'won', In German accent = 'von') :-)
> 2. Once
> 3. Oneself
> 4. Ouija Board  (I know, technically it's french but it is in the [English dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ouija-board)!!)

Comment: No idea why someone gave this a downvote.. corrected it with an upvote on my behalf.

Comment: Word #4 is definitely a word in English, whatever its origin might be.

Answer (score 3):

> Odin is sometimes pronounced Wodin?

Answer (score 3):

W

> **One** (Relating to unity) and derivatives thereof (once, ones, onesie... )
>  **Oneberry** (A herb "herb-paris" or "Paris quadrifolia") also a derivative of one - it has a single berry.
>  **Oneida** (A lake in the U.S., the native tribe from the East of it, and their language; also a city in central New York)
>  **Ouabain** (The clycoside $C_{29}H_{44}O_{12}$)
>  **Ouachita** (A river in North America)
>  **Ouagadougou** (The capital of Burkina Faso)
>  **Ouakari** (Variant spelling of Uakari, a monkey of the Amazon)
>  **Ouananiche** (A variety of Atlantic salmon found in lakes in S.E. Canada)
>  **Ouanderoo** (Variant of Wanderoo, a Sri Lankan langur)
>  **Ouija** [Board] (A U.S. trademark in popular usage, spiritualist communication device)
>  **Ouistiti** (A South American monkey)

V

> ?!

Answer (score 2):

It'd be difficult to find ones that don't begin with "one" :D

> 1. Oneway (it seems to have arguable spelling, could be one-way)
> 2. Onefold
> 3. Onetime
> 4. Oneness

Answer (score 1):

> One
>  Ones
>  Oneself
>  Onefold
>  Oneness 
>  Onetime
>  Oneown....

Basically all that starts with one.

Comment: ... except "onerous" `:)`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the words already posted that are

> derived from "one": "onesie" and "onesies".